# Размещение CSS

Tags: gwt, javascript, java, css

Начал писать библиотеку компонентов на GWT. Встал такой вопрос: Где лучше разместить стили к отдельным элементам? Стили могут располагаться в общем файле стилей, в java-коде, или же в раздельных файлах стилей. В последнем, не совсем понятно как реализовать. Общая идея уменьшить размер выходного файла, в моем случае это критично.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше правила стилей писать в файлах reset.css layout.css type.css style.css и т.д., например, а потом их склеивать и сжимать в all.css.